# Equivalent variables of binary expansion of integers

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a Integer number which is given. Based on this number I am able to create two vectors. For example $n=2$. Then I have:

```
 b2={00,01,10,11}
```

The corresponding variable vectors are:

```
 h0={{(1-x1)(1-x2)},{(1-x1)x2},{x1(1-x2)},{x1 x2}}

 h1={{y1 y2},{y1(1-y2)},{(1-y1)y2},{(1-y1)(1-y2)}}
```

So for the h0 we have the variable $x$ and for every $0$ in b2 we have $1-x$
And for every $1$ in b2 we have $x$. For h1 similarly but the other way around and over the variable $y$

For example of we have

b3={000,001,….,111} with 8 elements then I would like to have h0 and h1 as lists of variables x and y as indexed above like

```
 h0={{(1-x1)(1-x2)(1-x3)},…..,{x1 x2 x3}}
 h1={{y1 y2 y3},….., {(1-y1)(1-y2)(1-y3)}}
```

Could one automise this in Mathematica? I mean If I give and number $n$ I would like to obtain the variable vectors h0 and h1, which have size dependent on $n$ as exemplified above.

Comment: Something like what `Times @@@ MapIndexed[With[{xx = Symbol["x" <> IntegerString[#2[[2]]]]}, Replace[#, {0 -> 1 - xx, 1 -> xx}]] &, Tuples[{0, 1}, 2], {2}]` does?

Comment: @J.M. Seems good and how to extend it to other n?

Comment: I would suggest looking at the docs for `Tuples[]` so you can answer your own question.

Comment: Tuples [{0,1},3],{2}] worked. What is the role of {2} at the end?

Comment: @Seyhmus Note that the `{2}` at the end of that piece of code is part of the syntax of the enclosing [`Replace`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Replace.html), and not of `Tuples`

Answer (score 3):

```
n = 3;
xs = Array[Indexed[x, #] &, n];
bits = Tuples[{0, 1}, n];
h0 = MapIndexed[With[{col = Last@#2}, If[0 == #1, 1 - xs[[col]], xs[[col]]]] &, bits, {2}]
```

**Edit:**

That gives you `h0`. You can get `h1` the same way or as

```
ys = Array[Indexed[y, #] &, n];
h1 = h0 /. Thread[xs -> 1 - ys]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
ClearAll[f]
f[k_Integer, v_: x] := 
  Inner[Construct, 
        Tuples[{1 - # &, # &}, k], 
        Array[Indexed[v, #] &, k],
        Times
       ]
```

***Examples:***

```
f[2]
```

[image]

```
f[2] /. Indexed[_, i_] :> 1 - Indexed[y, i]
```

[image]

Alternatively, provide the symbol name as the second argument and post-process:

```
f[2, y] /. a_Indexed :> 1 - a
```

[image]

```
f[3]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Define a utility function.

```
Clear[bExpand]
bExpand[n_Integer /; n > 0, s_?LetterQ] := Module[
  {
   varlist = ToExpression[s <> ToString[#] & /@ Range[1, n]],
   t = Tuples[{True, False}, n],
   t1
   },
  t1 = (BooleanMinterms[{#}, varlist] & /@ t) /. {Not[a_] -> (1 - a)};
  If[n == 1, t1, Times @@@ t1]
  ]
```

---

**Usage** Choose a positive `n` and a valid letter to call the function. Reverse the output separately, if it is required.

```
bExpand[2, "x"] // Reverse
```

> {(1 - x1) (1 - x2), (1 - x1) x2, x1 (1 - x2), x1 x2}

```
bExpand[3, "g"]
```

> ```
> {g1 g2 g3, g1 g2 (1 - g3), g1 (1 - g2) g3, 
>  g1 (1 - g2) (1 - g3), (1 - g1) g2 g3, (1 - g1) g2 (1 - g3), (1 - 
>     g1) (1 - g2) g3, (1 - g1) (1 - g2) (1 - g3)}
> ```

and the edge case:

```
bExpand[1, "k"]
```

> {k1, 1 - k1}

---

**EDIT-1** to include @kglr's helpful comments (thanks)

```
Clear[bExpand2]
bExpand2[n_Integer /; n > 0, s_?LetterQ] := Module[
  {
   varlist = ToExpression[s <> ToString[#] & /@ Range[1, n]],
   t = Range[0, 2^n - 1],
   },
  (BooleanMinterms[{#}, varlist] & /@ t) /. {And -> Times, 
    Not -> (1 - # &)}
  ]
```

---

**EDIT-2** without using the `BooleanMinterms` function

```
Clear[bExpand3];
bExpand3[n_Integer /; n > 0, s_?LetterQ] := Module[
  {
   varlist = ToExpression[s <> ToString[#] & /@ Range[1, n]],
   t = IntegerDigits[#, 2, n] & /@ Range[0, 2^n - 1],
   tt
   },
  tt = Transpose[t];
  Times @@@ 
   Transpose@(Table[
      tt[[i]] /. {0 -> varlist[[i]], 1 -> (1 - varlist[[i]])}, {i, 1, 
       Length[tt]}])
  ]
```

Comment: You can also use `t = Range[0, 2^n - 1]` instead of `Tuples[{True, False},n]`. (+1)

Comment: also if you use  `{And -> Times, Not -> (1-#&))}` instead of  `{Not[a_] -> (1 - a)}`  you can avoid further processing with `Times`.